# How to Resolve Predis Connection Timeout

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, phpredis

i'm using predis integrated with laravel, in some case predis got connection timeout, but when i'm trying to connect redis server via cli, i got connected perfectly

can anyone help me how to resolve it ?

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException {#7222-connection: Predis\Connection\StreamConnection {#7171
-resource: null
-cachedId: null
#parameters: Predis\Connection\Parameters {#7178
  -parameters: array:5 [
    "host" => "Host"
    "password" => "Password"
    "port" => "6379"
    "database" => 0
    "scheme" => "tcp"
  ]
}
#initCommands: array:1 [
  0 => Predis\Command\RawCommand {#7218
    -slot: null
    -commandID: "SELECT"
    -arguments: array:1 [
      0 => 0
    ]
  }
]}#message: "Connection timed out [tcp://Host:6379]" #code: 110 #file:"./vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php" #line: 155
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the debug data your Host is set to `Host`. I'm assuming you got `redis` on a localhost setup, in your `.env` file set the following variable. Also your password seems off, adjust that also, most local redis installs has a blank password.

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=
```

If you got `redis` on a server, set your `ip` accordingly.